# Question about copy parameter in `Pandas.Series`

Tags: python, pandas, series

According to the help file of Series, the setting of copy "Only affects Series or 1d ndarray input"

```py
import numpy as np, pandas as pd
a = np.array(["c", "python", "java"])
s = pd.Series(a, copy = False)
s[2] = "julia"
print(a)   # a remains unchanged

a2 = np.array([1, 2, 3])
s2 = pd.Series(a2, copy = False)
s2[2] = 33
print(a2)   # a2 is changed

# but
a3 = np.array(["c", "python", "java"])
a3[2] = "julia"
print(a3)   # a3 is changed
```

Why?

Comment: from docs: `Due to input data type the Series has a view on the original data, so the data is changed as well.`

Comment: I suspect this has to do with the fact that strings are really an array of characters in a cell (essential not a 1-D), hence the `copy=True` parameter in pd.Series when storing strings doesn't work.

Comment: String is immutable, but np.array with string type elements is mutable, see a3 for example.

Answer (score 0):

When a Series is constructed with a backing `np.ndarray`, says `a`, whose `dtype.kind == 'U'` (unicode), pandas will try to convert `a`'s elements to `str` via an internal method called [`ensure_string_array`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/6e1a0401420bffd282f3cf8b57e653a39e373d3b/pandas/_libs/lib.pyx#L699).

That method returns `np.asarray(a, dtype="object")`, which is **always a copy of `a` regardless of your copy setting**. This is because the dtype of `a` (`'<U6'` in your example) and the dtype passed as argument (`"object"`) to [`np.asarray`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.asarray.html) don't match. You can verify that the Series is being backed by a copy and not the original array by

```
>>> a = np.array(["c", "python", "java"])
>>> s = pd.Series(a, copy=False)
>>> a.dtype.kind
'U'
>>> s.dtype.kind
'O'
>>> s.__array__() is a
False
```

To escape this conversion route, you can explicitly specify `a` to be of dtype `object`, in which case `ensure_string_array` won't be invoked and instead [`np.astype`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/6e1a0401420bffd282f3cf8b57e653a39e373d3b/pandas/core/construction.py#L811) will be called with the appropriate `copy` setting.

```
>>> a = np.array(["c", "python", "java"], dtype="object")  # Note the dtype
>>> s = pd.Series(a, copy=False)
>>> s.__array__() is a
True
>>> s[2] = "julia"
>>> print(a)
['c' 'python' 'julia']
```